# Can Paypal Payments Standard accept a value and pass it along to the webpage users are redirected to after successful payment?

Tags: paypal

I am setting up Paypal Payments Standard for a website; I am using the Buy Now button that, when clicked, takes the user to Paypal for them to enter their payment information.

Now here's the rub - when the user makes a successful payment, I want to send them to a *partner website* and I want to pass along the key they just purchased.

So in a nutshell there would be this interaction:

1. User visits my site and a Buy Now form is generated with a hidden field like so (along with the other requisite Paypal-specific fields): `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="xxx" />`
2. The user clicks the Buy Now button and is taken to Paypal.

   a. If they cancel the purchase they are returned to my website. (Ideally in this case the key value would *not* be included in the return URL.)

   b. If the payment is successful the user is redirected to www.someothersite.com/payment.aspx and in either a POST or the querystring the key that was in the hidden field is passed along.

I am aware that such a scenario could be handled using the Paypal API via the Payments Professional product (rather than the Standard product), but that's not an option for a variety of reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the value to the return URL you include in the button code, and that would work (usually), but it's not recommended...because of the usually part.

Even if you have Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account there is no guarantee that your user will actually make it there.  You'll end up with people closing their browser before the redirect, for example, so they'll never see the final page and any code on that page won't get run for that order.

Instead, you need to use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  This will be triggered every time no matter what, and you can process the data in the IPN however you need to: send email notifications to parties involved, updating databases, hit 3rd party web service API's, etc.

So you'll actually use your own basic return URL similar to your own cancel URL, and use IPN to handle post-order processing.